# UIView.animate not executed in PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have been working on the following code for the entire day now and simply cannot find the problem. I would like to save a video and upon completion make certain buttons or spinners (dis-)appear. All the buttons are setup in the `viewDidLoad` and so to say exist (they're optionals, therefore also the optional chaining). My problem is the animations in the `if` clause are never executed. Only sometimes if I place breakpoints before every line of code, it works which really makes me wonder (btw: the breakpoints don't indicate anything unusual). Further, if I replace the code of the `if success2 == true` with the code of the `else` (`if success2 == false`), it works (after the alert pops up). I pretty much quadruple-checked my code and just cannot find what I am doing wrong. Has anyone an idea as to what could be the problem and how it could be solved?

Sorry for the huge block of code:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    if let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url) {
        let assetCollectionChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: albumAssetCollection)
        let enumeration: NSArray = [assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!]
        assetCollectionChangeRequest?.addAssets(enumeration)
    }
}, completionHandler: { (success2: Bool, error2: Error?) in
    if success2 == true {
        // prompt that the video has been saved
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            if let checkButton = self.checkButton, let saveSpinner = self.saveSpinner, let resetButton = self.resetButton {
                saveSpinner.alpha = 0
                checkButton.alpha = 1
                resetButton.alpha = 1
            }
        }) { (completed: Bool) in
            if completed == true {
                if let saveSpinner = self.saveSpinner {
                    saveSpinner.stopAnimating()
                    self.timeLimitReached = false
                    self.changeClipsCount()
                }
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 3, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    if let checkButton = self.checkButton, let saveButton = self.saveButton {
                        checkButton.alpha = 0
                        saveButton.alpha = 1
                    }
                }) { (completed: Bool) in }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // prompt that the video has not been saved
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Something failed!", message: "The video could not be saved.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                if let saveButton = self.saveButton, let saveSpinner = self.saveSpinner {
                    saveButton.alpha = 1
                    saveSpinner.alpha = 0
                }
            }) { (completed: Bool) in
                if let saveSpinner = self.saveSpinner {
                    saveSpinner.stopAnimating()
                    self.timeLimitReached = false
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Is the completionHandler called by Apple code on the main thread or on a background thread?

Also as a side note, if you're using optional chaining you don't need to `if let checkButton = checkButton`, you can just use `checkButton?.alpha = 1`

Comment: It wasn't on the main thread! However, I am still not sure why this was the case (explanation would be much appreciated)... Put all the code of the `if` in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` and now it works (after checking if it was on the main thread using `Thread.isMainThread`)! Thank you so much!

Comment: I've answered properly with a better explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post my comment as an answer with a bit of a better explanation.

For `UIView` animations to work they must be used on the main thread (just like all other UIKit stuff!).

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrary/1620743-performchanges/#discussion) for `PHPhotoLibrary`, Apple state that:

> Photos executes both the change block and the completion handler block on an arbitrary serial queue. To update your app’s UI as a result of a change, dispatch that work to the main queue.

This means that you should expect to handle the response from Apple as though it's coming from somewhere other than the main thread. So an easy fix for this is to call:

`DispatchQueue.main.async {}` and wrap that around the code where you want to do UIKit stuff.

The reason Apple don't do their work on the main thread is because potentially the work they're doing could be significant, and it would hog the main thread which would make your UI sluggish and unresponsive.

I'd also recommend a few little tweaks to your code just to make it easier to read. In the completion handler I would extract the code out into a function, and then all you have to do is wrap that function call in a `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` call rather than the whole block of code you want to animate.

Also don't forget to make use of one of Swift's best language features: [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html). This means that you don't have to check whether something exists before trying to use it, if it doesn't exist it'll just bail out. So you can safely do things like this:

```
checkButton?.alpha = 1
```